# Cron that needs more time than he's allowed to

Tags: cron, crontab

My crontab runs a cron every 5 minutes... If the cron needs more than 5 minutes to run, can this be a problem??
Can the problem be with the commands the cron runs?

Thanks for your answer ;-)

Answer (score 4):

`cron` should have no problem running your task again even though the first one isn't finished.

Although, a problem could arise depending on the commands you are running (i.e. if they both write to the same file)

Comment: If having two instances of the script running concurrently is an issue, you want to use a lockfile - or things like `pgrep` to check if another instance is running - to either make the second instance wait or quit, if it detects another instance is running.